# django allauth: add more fields to signup form

Tags: django-allauth

I have `django-allauth` package installed I am trying to add some fields from my `User model`
to the signup form of `allauth`

```
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm
class MyCustomSignupForm(SignupForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','email','mobile','city','district','state','country','pin_code')
```

But I dont see many of these fields in my `signup` form at `/accounts/signup`.

How can i do this

Answer (score 0):

it works for me. There are several good guides on this topic. Ovveride the custom signup form with your own. This is done in the forms.py

```py
    from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm
    
    class CustomignupForm(SignupForm):
       def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # Call the init of the parent class
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields[_("mobile")] = forms.CharField(required=True)
        self.fields[_("city")] = forms.CharField(required=True)
        self.fields[_("district")] = forms.CharField(required=True)
        #"Rest of your fields"
    # Put in custom signup logic
       def custom_signup(self, request, user):
        # Set the user's type from th form reponse
        user.mobile= self.cleaned_data[_("mobile")]
        user.city= self.cleaned_data[_("city")]
      #"Rest of your fields"

        user.save()
        return user
```